# ASP.NET MVC AspNetUserClaims How can I read, write and update data in the table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, claims

This is my first question in StackOverflow :) so please don't judge me strong :) Ok. Here we go.

I'm new in ASP.NET MVC Framework, and trying to implement multi-language in my site. So I had added the drop-down language list to the _LoginPartial.cshtml:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">@(MEDONET.Resources.IndexTexts.Language)<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Кыргызча", "Change", "Language", new { lang = "ky" }, null)</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Русский", "Change", "Language", new { lang = "ru" }, null)</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("English", "Change", "Language", new { lang = "en" }, null)</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("O'zbekcha", "Change", "Language", new { lang = "uz" }, null)</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

As you can see, I am passing selected Language abbreviation to the Change method of the Language controller. In the LanguageController I have the code looking like this:

```
public ActionResult Change(string lang)
    {
        if (lang != null)
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                //var user =  _userManager.FindByName(User.Identity.Name);
                //_userManager.AddClaim(user.Id, new Claim("Language", lang));
                //var claims = _userManager.GetClaims(user.Id);

                ////User.RemoveClaimIfExists("Language");
                ////var claims = new List<Claim>();
                ApplicationDbContext mycontext = new ApplicationDbContext();
                UserStore<ApplicationUser> mystore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(mycontext);
                ApplicationUserManager UserMan = new ApplicationUserManager(mystore);
                //ApplicationUser _user = UserMan.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
                UserMan.AddClaim(User.Identity.GetUserId(), new Claim("Language", lang));

                //UserMan.RemoveClaim(User.Identity.GetUserId(), User.GetClaim("Language"));
                //User.AddClaim(lang);

            }
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(lang);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(lang);

            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Language");
            cookie.Value = lang;
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

            return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
        }
        return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
    }
```

As you could notice, I was trying A LOT of different ways to implement the feature. And after day of the torments it became working. But I am not sure my Frankenshtain is the best way to write a Claim to the AspNetUserClaims table. So this is my first question:

> 1) How can I improve my writing claims code?

The second question is much near to the first:

> 2) How can I update existing user claim?

And finally the last third obvious for my knowledge level question is:

> 3) How to read the stored claims?

Once set claim needs to be read in the next sessions. So therefor I have created the Claims class, added there this

```
public static string GetClaimValue(this IPrincipal currentPrincipal, string key)
    {
        var identity = currentPrincipal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        if (identity == null)
            return null;

        var claim = identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == key);
        return claim?.Value;
    }
```

code and call it from Login method of AccountController:

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Language");
                string lang = GetClaimValue("Language");
                if (lang == null) // language was not selected befor
                    lang = "ru"; 
                Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cookie.Value);
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(cookie.Value);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Bu as you could guess I always get Russian language instead of Kyrgyz which abbr "ky" stored in the AspNetUserClaims table.

That's it :) I hope it wasn't too much table talks in here. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to skip your first question, as it's hard for me to answer without seing all the contexts in which you use your claims-code. However, for you other questions:

> 2) How can I update existing user claim?

You can use an approach like this:

```
    public static void AddUpdateClaim(this IPrincipal currentPrincipal, string key, string value)
    {
        var identity = currentPrincipal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        if (identity == null)
            return;

        // check for existing claim and remove it
        var existingClaim = identity.FindFirst(key);
        if (existingClaim != null)
            identity.RemoveClaim(existingClaim);

        // add new claim
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(key, value));
        var authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        authenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant = new AuthenticationResponseGrant(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity), new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = true });
    }
```

Now you can use it from any controller like this:

```
User.AddUpdateClaim("Language", "ru");
```

> 3) How to read the stored claims?

Something like this:

```
    public static string GetClaimValue(this IPrincipal principal, string type)
    {
        var user = principal as ClaimsPrincipal;
        var claim = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == type);

        if (claim != null) return claim.Value;

        throw new Exception($"Claim with type {type} not set");
    }
```

Both methods are extension-metods, usable on the Controller.User object.

EDIT: As a response to your comment, this is how you could create the claims identity to begin with:

```
 var ident = new ClaimsIdentity(
                new[] { 
                    new Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider", "ASP.NET Identity", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"),               
                },
                DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

//Add default language to claims
ident.AddClaim(new Claim("Language", "ru"));

HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(ident);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! I have already tried this code, but for no reason It's not working.

Comment: This code     var user = currentPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal;
            var claim = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == type);

            if (claim != null) return claim.Value;
            else return "uz"; always returns me 'uz' instead of 'en' which is stored in the table

Comment: Added some extra code, as an example. This would typically be used in a login method

Comment: No, bro, I am successfully adding values to the store but can't retrieve them from there

Comment: Well it doesn’t seem like you’re successfully adding the values, if they are null when you try to retreive them again

Comment: But they are there! You can check it by yourself `<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=SQL5031.site4now.net;Initial Catalog=DB_A2A64E_Lutpulla;User Id=DB_A2A64E_Lutpulla_admin;Password=Errdicgk234!;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />` medonet.kg

Answer (score 0):

> For updating claims

```
// GET: Language
    public ActionResult Change(string lang)
    {
        if(lang != null)
        {

            if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var claims = new List<Claim>();

                ApplicationDbContext mycontext = new ApplicationDbContext();
                UserStore<ApplicationUser> mystore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(mycontext);
                ApplicationUserManager UserMan = new ApplicationUserManager(mystore);
                ApplicationUser _user = UserMan.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

                var claim = _user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ClaimType == "Language");

                if (claim != null) // User have Language claim the table 
                {
                    if (claim.ClaimValue != lang) // and chosen language doesn't match it
                    {
                        UserMan.RemoveClaim(User.Identity.GetUserId(), new Claim("Language", claim.ClaimValue));
                        UserMan.AddClaimAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), new Claim("Language", lang)); 
                    }
                }
                else if(claim == null)
                {
                    UserMan.AddClaimAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), new Claim("Language", lang));
                }

            }
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(lang);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(lang);

            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Language");
            cookie.Value = lang;
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);


            return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
        }
        return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
    }
```

In this Change action I'm actually reading the claim, but if want to read it while login in, I do something like that:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Language");
                cookie.Value = "ru";
                var user = UserManager.FindByEmail(model.Email);

                    var claim = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ClaimType == "Language");

                    if (claim == null)
                    {
                        cookie.Value = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name.ToString(); // interface language used befor logining in
                    }
                    else
                        cookie.Value = claim.ClaimValue; // Language from the UserClaim 

                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cookie.Value);
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(cookie.Value);
                Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```